# Web server (IIS) and database mirroring (Postgresql)

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, web-server, iis-7, postgresql

Recently our web-server crashed and we had to recover everything from a backup which took the whole day(totally unacceptable in our business).

So my question is, how can I create a complete mirror of the server that I can use (switch dns to) in case the same disaster happens in the future?

Our main server is on Amazon with Windows 2008/IIS + Postgresql 9.1. I was thinking on creating the same server on a different location as a complete mirror with the database replication. But I'm not sure how to implement IIS instance mirroring over the internet...

So my question is, how can I create a complete mirror of the server that I can use (switch dns to) in case the same disaster happens in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Although Postgresql has a large number of replication options, if I understand your problem right, it is more about fundamental stability of operating systems and server applications, IIS & Postgres.

There is a similar answer provided for Amazon EC2 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940265/deploying-a-high-availability-postresql-9-0-on-amazon-ec2-with-pgpool-ii

Personally, I'd be more partial to a VMware solution using something like the following:

```
circuit diversity / ISP diversity
Vcenter
Netapp
VMs with HA & FT configuration
Assumes no single point of failure in above.
```

The VMs should use the same DNS information if a FT event occurs.

You can expand this via F5 load balancers and duplicate sites if needed.

References:

VMware Fault Tolerance Datasheet 
http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/VMware-Fault-Tolerance-FT-DS-EN.pdf

VMware / F5 
http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/partners/desktop/f5-for-virtualized-it-environments.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that I won't be able to implement VM approach since my mirror server would be on our local hosting facility. So, the main server is on the West Coast and the mirror would be on the East Coast.

Comment: You can have either both DBs at the same location, or 3 DBs, lets say West Coast A, B, and East Coast C?  The DB location can be independent of the VM locations, if VMs are needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, the requirement was to keep it simple - 2 servers, syncing the data between the master server and the slave along with the db replication